# Toggle metered connection

Tags: windows, windows-update

Windows 10 allows the user to schedule when updates are applied, but not when they are downloaded.

One way to control Windows 10 update downloads is to manually define the wifi connection as a metered connection, and then to manually set it back to unmetered again.

My ISP allows free downloads between midnight and 6am.  It would therefore be best if I could schedule Windows updates to happen during this time.

Is it possible to use Task Scheduler and a Windows script to change from metered to unmetered on a schedule.

If yes, any pointers on how to do it?

Thanks
Brendon

Answer (score 11):

First, use this command to get names of your wlan profiles:

```
netsh wlan show profiles
```

Second, use this command to get current settings:

```
netsh wlan show profile name="Your profile name"
```

It prints "Cost : Fixed" if connection is metered, "Cost : Unrestricted" if non-metered

To change between metered and non-metered use these:

```
netsh wlan set profileparameter name="Your profile name" cost=Unrestricted

netsh wlan set profileparameter name="Your profile name" cost=Fixed
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks JIT. Just to add to that, you can use

```
netsh mbn
```

to run the same commands for a cellular connection.